# Delay process start until parent process close

Tags: c#, .net

I have a process A that start a process B. The process B change some files of process A, so I need a delay in process B for let process A close himself.

for the moment I have founded two solutions.

Solution 1: quote from [link](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/464492-c-process-with-delay/) "The only way I can think of doing that would be to write a second program that waits 30 seconds and loads the desired program, you call that program and close the first program, the second waits 30 seconds then loads the one you wanted to in the first place."

This work, but a third programm is a little to poor elegant if you know what I mean.

Solution2: Simple, just put a Thread.Sleep in process B before logic start(I have control of process A and B). This work too, and is not to bad idea...

I ask because I´m looking for a way to pass parameters on the call on proces A to processB.start , so it can the more clean/elegant solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code for how you're starting your processes? Will [`Process.WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx) work? As the name implies, it starts a process and then holds all execution until that process has finished, then it resumes.

Comment: That doesnt work for me, i need the process A close before process B star running, Process.WaitforExit() is the opposite. I repeat, Process B will try to change files of Process A, if process A is running, process B will not be able to do the changes.

Comment: Pass the PID of process A to process B, open the process from B and then do a WaitForExit(), then do the file modification

Comment: The process B is the one changing the files, passing the PID of A to process B will help if I make a processA.kill() from process B before changing the files. But i prefer Process A close himself.

Comment: Another option is to use a Mutex.  Process A would hold it til it is done and B would wait until it can grab it before doing it's work.

Comment: If process A is closing itself, you can still check if it's running when B starts, and if it is running, wait for it to close as suggested...

Comment: @KiraCrafter You don't need to kill the process, you pass the PID from A to B to ope the process (Process.GetProcessById) and then do Process.WaitForExit, that will block te execution until A has finished

Comment: @MarkJansen so you are sayng that I pass A PID to B, and then B make a processA.waitforExit ? thats a very good solution, thx!

Comment: Sorry @Gusman I missundesrtood the first commnent, it´s a pretty good solution

Comment: KiraCrafter: My suggestion is simply what @Gusman said, but then re-worded.

Comment: Yes @MarkJansen when you put the comment i noticed that it was the same solution of Gusman, but i did not undestrood the answeer in the moment, so if it wasnt for you i would keep not understood Gusman commnt. so..again, thx!! both of you! and again...sorry my anglish... cuban guy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 actual ways to do this.

First, you can use OS level synchronization objects like [`Mutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx). In your first app create new named `Mutex` and [release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex(v=vs.110).aspx) it before app closed. In second app wait Mutex released by [`WaitOne`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx).

First process should create new mutex and block other processes:

```
Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "SomeName");
// start second process
mtx.ReleaseMutex();
```

Second process:

```
Mutex mtx = new Mutex(false, "SomeName");

// next line will block current thread until mutex will be released
mtx.WaitOne();

// your logic here
```

Also you can [check running processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) in your second app and wait when first app will closed:

```
while(Process.GetProcessesByName("YourFirstProcessName").Any())
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Keep in mind that both solutions involve overhead because Mutex is an operating system level synchronization object and `Process.GetProcessesByName` also calls external API.

Comment: Why complicate a very simple task using named mutexes when you can just wait the process to end??

Comment: @Gusman You can wait process exit from initiator code but in the question's scenario we will need to exit of an initiator application code.